# What is a good way of implementing per-page JavaScript in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Trying new things in Ruby - on each page I'm doing very rich stuff with jquery. Obviously if I put all the jquery into application.js it's going to grow very large very quickly.

Is it a good approach to lazy-load a page-specific js file at the end? eg:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getScript("/javascripts/this_pages_scripts.js");

});
</script>
```

Is there a rails-way way of doing this? I am aware of the new.js.erb etc. files and ujs, but I am still talking about more page-specific js - you know, drag and drop initialisers, dialog creators, etc.

Thank you very much.

Comment: When you say "large very quickly" you might be exaggerating. 20-30KB of JavaScript is a lot, yet it's not "large" because it can be shipped to the browser compressed to about 3KB and will be cached between requests if your server is configured properly. It's only larger libraries like jQuery-UI or Google Maps that should concern you, and not loading those on pages that don't use them can help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways that I use:

For tiny, trivial scripts that are just adding a bit of eye-candy, I often include them inline in the template they modify (just like you've shown), because it is easier for me to keep track of this way.

For anything that's more than one or two little lines I keep it unobtrusive, but load it using `content_for`

My Application Layout looks like this (in HAML):

```
= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.144.min','rails','jquery.tools','application'
= yield :scripts
```

The important part is `yield :scripts`. Then in a page where I need some javascript I do:

```
- content_for :scripts do
  = javascript_include_tag 'photo_form'
```

This loads the javascript in the header, but only if the given template is shown. `content_for` sends stuff to the `yield` method with the corresponding name.

You can stick a yield block like that anywhere -- **I also have one just before the closing body tag**. Yield / content_for is really handy.

*Note as tadman pointed out in the comments, anything that doesn't have to be loaded in the head should be loaded at the end of the page.*

One last thing to be aware of, if you have something more complex you can also use instance variables between your templates and your application view. For instance, I have a menubar in my app that's in the application layout. So, sometimes I want to trigger a context-specific button or additional row of buttons only on certain pages.

In my application layout I call a partial which renders the menu, the menu code looks like:

```
#menubar (normal menu stuff)
  - if @special_menu
    #special_menu
```

So, then in any template you can do:

```
- @special_menu = true
```

... and for that page the given menu will appear. You can also do this in controller actions, I have one controller where I added a before filter that sets one of the menu flags to true. You could do the same thing for any complex set of javascript stuff you might want to conditionally include.

Most of these ideas I got from watching this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title

You should take a look!

Comment: Whenever possible, JavaScript files should be loaded very late in the document to avoid them holding up page rendering. Analytics should be the last thing before the `<body>` tag is closed, for instance. jQuery needs to be loaded early, as does anything else that uses `$(document).ready(...)` for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Set a symbol to represent the filename in your header and call it in the controller

```
@script = "prototype"
```

Then in the view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag @script %>
```

Or to load multiple

```
@scripts = ["prototype", "dropdown"]
```

Then

```
<% @scripts.each do |s| %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag s %>
<% end &>
```

Comment: Then just make it different in each controller

Comment: This doesn't really answer the bulk of the question about what the Rails convention is for structuring your javascript across files. And by the way, you can use the splat operator to expand an array to arguments a la `js = %w{foo bar}; javascript_include_tag *js`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and a custom feature detection library to handle this.

Then I have a single line to include the requirejs script and its `data-main` attribute in my layout / master / shared view page. (I'm not familiar with rails as such, but it's the same with any other MVC).

I've written a nice answer about this somewhere else. You might be able to find it.